# Building uclibc linux 3.10-2 (Debian jessie x86_64) fails due to missing types

Tags: c, linux, debian, header-files, uclibc

I'm trying to build uClibc 0.9.27 <sup>[1]</sup> on x86_64 with the linux kernel 3.10-2-amd64. I can verify that it builds on Ubuntu 12.04.3 with the 3.2.0-49-generic kernel. When running make, it manages to build a lot of object files but eventually reaches `CC libc/inet/if_index.os`, complaining with

```
In file included from /usr/include/linux/kernel.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/linux/netlink.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/linux/rtnetlink.h:5,
                 from libc/inet/netlinkaccess.h:32,
                 from libc/inet/if_index.c:36:
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:8: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__kernel_long_t'
In file included from /usr/include/linux/rtnetlink.h:6,
                 from libc/inet/netlinkaccess.h:32,
                 from libc/inet/if_index.c:36:
/usr/include/linux/if_link.h:317: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__be16'
```

I verified that the types exist in files that I gather *should* have been sucked in. In the case of `__kernel_long_t`, the include files look like this:

```
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h includes <linux/types.h>
/usr/include/linux/types.h includes <linux/posix_types.h>
/usr/include/linux/posix_types.h includes <asm/posix_types.h>
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/posix_types.h includes <asm/posix_types_64.h>
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/posix_types_64.h includes <asm-generic/posix_types.h>
/usr/include/asm-generic/posix_types.h typedefs __kernel_long_t
```

**So, where does that error come from, and how can I fix it?**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Yes, I know the newest version is 0.9.33.2, but I need that particular version.

Comment: Did you install some `linux-headers` package?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, I have `linux-headers-3.10-2-{amd64,common}`.

Comment: Are you *sure* 3.10-2 `asm-generic/posix_types.h` defines `__kernel_long_t`? Can you check if setting `HOSTCFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -D__kernel_long_t=long` in `uClibc-0.9.27/Rules.mak` fixes the problem?

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Yes, I just re-checked. `/usr/include/asm-generic/posix_types.h` has that typedef (`/usr/include/asm-generic/posix_types.h:  14       :typedef long  __kernel_long_t;`). I also followed your suggestion, to try to pass the define directly, but `HOSTCFLAGS doesn't seem to be expanded by the make system` (nor does `BUILD_CFLAGS`). I tried passing it directly to the compiler and indeed the error goes away (as expected) but the next pops up (`__kernel_ulong_t`). I could define all these types, but that'd probably just quiet the *symptom*. It'd be a last resort, though. Thanks.

Comment: Later uClibc versions added the two typedefs (`typedef long __kernel_long_t;` and `typedef unsigned long __kernel_ulong_t;`) to `libc/sysdeps/linux/i386/bits/kernel_types.h` (actually to all `libc/sysdeps/linux/*/bits/kernel_types.h`), as they were added to by kernels 3.4 and later. Perhaps that would suffice?

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I managed to [patch it somehow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18722884/430766) but it's probably not yet a 100% perfect. Builds, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution seems to be to backport a newer version of `libc/inet/netlinkacces.h` to the older version. The `__kernel_long_t` problem goes away by avoiding an include (if necessary, that would have to be patched in `kernel_types.h`, because the defines intentionally shadow the include guards of the headers in `/usr/include`) and the other type(s) can be properly included by the following patch:

```
index 417d83a..1b9c857 100644
--- a/libc/inet/netlinkaccess.h
+++ b/libc/inet/netlinkaccess.h
@@ -21,16 +21,7 @@

 #include <features.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
-#include <sys/types.h>
-
-#define _LINUX_TYPES_H
-typedef uint8_t __u8;
-typedef uint16_t __u16;
-typedef uint32_t __u32;
-typedef uint64_t __u64;
-typedef int32_t __s32;
-#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
-#include <linux/netlink.h>
+#include <unistd.h>

 /* Should prob be a configure option or something */
 #ifndef __ASSUME_NETLINK_SUPPORT
```

This is basically the change between the old `netlinkaccess.h` and the one in the newer version (diffing of the preprocessed files suggested by [ash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18711648/430766) hinted me to this).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say where the error comes from without looking carefully at the code in question.  Most likely is a case that the package itself is not compatible with the environment within which you are attempting to build the software.  With that said, it's possible to track it down, if you are willing to do so.  From there, the solution is likely either changing settings at the start of the build process, or modifying the code to correct  a mistake.

This problem is tricky to track down since it's a third-party package performing the includes.  And, if it's written to build on multiple architectures, it will likely contain a lot of preprocessor directives that make it hard to even know which code is actually being used.

I recommend capturing the command that generates the error (looks like that may be `CC libc/inet/if_index.os` although CC of an os file seems odd), then modify the `cc` command to capture the preprocessed output.

For example, to get preprocessed output from this:

```
cc -c prog.c -o prog.o
```

Use this intead:

```
cc -E prog.c >prog.i
```

Then search though prog.i for the line in question.  It's tricky to locate specific line numbers, so it's best to search for text - although that can be tricky too since some words will be replaced by the preprocessor.  The good news here is that the output will tell you exactly what the compiler is trying to compile - after all includes have been processed and macros applied.  Just "pure C" code.

Do this on the version that works and the one that does not, and see where `__kernel_long_t` gets pulled into the build on the good one, and then try to find why that's not happening on the failing one.

Note the lines that look like this:

```
# 443 "/usr/include/stdio.h"
```

mean "line 443" of "/usr/include/stdio.h" is the next line in the output file.

To see where a definition comes into the sources, search up from the line that contains the definition, probably a typedef as indicated in the question, and search up for the first line above that with a filename - that's the file from which it was obtained.  Walk up more to see where that file was pulled in.  Note that it won't necessarily be the next file above, so verify against the original sources.  Doing this, eventually you'll find the part of the packaged sources that included a file with that definition.  Then it should be possible to figure out why either that line isn't used in the other build, or that the same include doesn't lead to the definition of the type.

Note that I'm assuming that the error messages posted mean the problem is the missing definition for `__kernel_long_t`.  The error could mean something just before the use of that type is a problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I actually looked at the preprocessed file, but I didn't make the leap to actually compare both versions. I'm giving it a try, thanks.

Comment: sure thing - good luck.  These can be tricky to solve.  Wish I had a more definitive answer for you.

Comment: Another idea.  I know you need the specific version, but this might be fixed in a newer version.  Did you try building the latest to see if it has the same problem?

Comment: Huh, the odd thing is, that the struct that *uses* the "missing" types isn't even included in the "working" system, there just isn't any trace of `__kernel_long_t` (and friends) in the entire preprocessed file. I suspect it might have to do with something uclibc specific (since it replaces the standard libc). Trying out the newest uclibc version next.

Comment: Seems to work now. Your suggestion prompted me to find the fix, so unless somebody whips up a better explanation of what's going on in the next 5 days, bounty's yours :)